# Unit testing JavaScript meant for the browser with Jest and JSDOM

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, jsdom

I'm trying to create unit tests for JavaScript that modifies the DOM in a page.
For example:

```js
function setBodyTo(str) {
    document.body.innerHTML = str;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = "lib.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
              setBodyTo("bar")
              })
          </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        foo
    </body>
</html>
```

I have been playing with Jest, and [every](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration) [example](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-start-unit-testing-javascript/) I could find was about testing Node code, adding the `module.exports setBodyTo` equivalent to the js file, so tests could be written with Jest.

I know how to run browser code for my tests using JSDOM.
However:

If I make this file into a Node module by including the exports line, I am able to write and run unit tests on it, get coverage reports, etc. But this code is then no longer meant for the browser, which is obviously not what I want.

If I load the page into JSDOM and make a test where JSDOM runs the Javascript on it, I don't think the test runner will know this file has run at all (in order to gather coverage). This is, besides the [various](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1914) [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711655/jsdom-not-loading-or-not-running-external-scripts-in-page) I've seen other people having getting JSDOM to read the script.

In short:

- Is there a way to make browser code into a node module in order to test it?
- Is there a way to load the functions in a node module into the browser?
- Am I about this a completely wrong way and there is a completely different approach that I've missed?

Comment: A different approach could be to use Cypress for this (eg https://www.cypress.io/blog/2018/02/05/when-can-the-test-start/). Using the example you gave, you could check if the page renders with the body content as "bar"?